# What does Average value mean in Summary Report in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I Have a Thread Group created in my Test Plan. I have set the Thread Group to run 20 Threads with Ramp Up Period as 0 and Loop Count as 1.

Now i have created 5 JDBC Sampler Request each which runs different queries against the same Database, so when i start the test , it should kick start 100 queries (20 * 5)

I also generated a Summary report and copied pasted parts of that report.

```
Sampler Label          No of Requests per Sampler   Average( in milliseconds)
-------------          --------------------------      --------------------------
MYSQL JDBC Request 1    20                         8571
MySQL JDBC Request 2    20                         5154
MySQL JDBC Request 3    20                         5927
MySQL JDBC Request 4    20                         1290
MySQL JDBC Request 5    20                         1449
TOTAL                   100                        4478
```

In the Summary Report taht i have compiled above, what does average of 4478 milliseconds mean?
Does this mean that it took 4478 milliseconds to run 20 threads on an average ? or does it mean that it took 4478 milliseconds to run 100 queries?..can someone help me here. I could not find this information anywhere in the Jmeter apache documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably average time to execute the query, no?

Comment: can you please  clarify what you mean ?..do you mean 4478 for 100 queries or does that mean its 4470 milliseconds per query or do you mean 4478 for 20 threads?..I am confused. need some help here. Not able to interpret the numbers. Thanks

Comment: The average in the `TOTAL`s line gives the average query time calculated over all 100 queries.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So does that mean the average time it took to execute a single query under this load is 4478 ms /per query ?

Answer (score 0):

As per this documentation:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report

Average : The average elapsed time of a set of results

So it means its it:

> Sum of all request's response time  / total number of requests